# I am using ASP.NET and Entity Framework (without core) with react js

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this controller action method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "UserID,UserName,UserPW,UserLoc,LngID,DictionaryChange,DateEtry,EntryBy,UserEnabled,UserDept,UpdateBy,UpdateDate,UserSafeBox,MainMenuBGColor,SubMenuBGColor,MainMenuFont,SubMenuFont,MainMenuForeColor,SubMenuForeColor,MainlblBGCol,SublblBGCol,CheckboxSelections,ModifiedCheckboxSelections")] tblUserInfo tblUserInfo, string CheckboxSelections, string ModifiedCheckboxSelections)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Checkbox Selections: {CheckboxSelections}");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Entry(tblUserInfo).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            // Check if CheckboxSelections is not null
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CheckboxSelections))
            {
                // Convert the comma-separated string to an array
                var selectionsArray = CheckboxSelections.Split(',');

                // Remove unchecked checkboxes from tblUserMainForms
                var uncheckedMainForms = db.tblUserMainForms
                        .Where(u => u.UserID == tblUserInfo.UserID && selectionsArray.Contains(u.MformNm))
                        .ToList();

                foreach (var uncheckedMainForm in uncheckedMainForms)
                {
                    db.tblUserMainForms.Remove(uncheckedMainForm);
                }

                // Remove unchecked checkboxes from tblUserSubMenus
                var uncheckedSubMenus = db.tblUserSubMenus
                        .Where(u => u.UserID == tblUserInfo.UserID && selectionsArray.Contains(u.subFrmNm))
                        .ToList();

                foreach (var uncheckedSubMenu in uncheckedSubMenus)
                {
                    db.tblUserSubMenus.Remove(uncheckedSubMenu);
                }

                // Process CheckboxSelections (for new selections)
                foreach (var newSelection in selectionsArray)
                {
                    if (!db.tblUserMainForms.Any(u => u.UserID == tblUserInfo.UserID && u.MformNm == newSelection))
                    {
                        // Checkbox is the first from any select item, save to tblUserMainForm
                        tblUserMainForm userMainForm = new tblUserMainForm
                            {
                                UserID = tblUserInfo.UserID,
                                MformNm = newSelection
                            };

                        db.tblUserMainForms.Add(userMainForm);
                    }
                    else if (!db.tblUserSubMenus.Any(u => u.UserID == tblUserInfo.UserID && u.subFrmNm == newSelection))
                    {
                        // Checkbox is not the first, save to tblUserSubMenu
                        tblUserSubMenu userSubMenu = new tblUserSubMenu
                            {
                                UserID = tblUserInfo.UserID,
                                subFrmNm = newSelection
                            };
                        db.tblUserSubMenus.Add(userSubMenu);
                    }
                }

                // Process ModifiedCheckboxSelections
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ModifiedCheckboxSelections))
                {
                    var modifiedSelectionsArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(ModifiedCheckboxSelections);

                    // Handle the modified selections as needed
                }

                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the exception for debugging
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
            // You might want to handle the exception differently, e.g., return a custom error view
            return View("Error");
        }
    }

    return View(tblUserInfo);
}
```

And I have this `handleSubmit` method in the `SelectMenu.jsx` file:

```
handleSubmit = async (event) => {
     event.preventDefault();

     const { checkboxSelections, modifiedCheckboxSelections } = this.state;

     // Debug: Check if data is correctly populated
     console.log("Selected Checkboxes:", checkboxSelections);
     console.log("Modified Checkboxes:", modifiedCheckboxSelections);

     const formData = new FormData(document.forms[0]);

     // Append UserID
     formData.append('UserID', document.getElementById("UserID").value);

     // Append CheckboxSelections as a comma-separated string
     formData.append('CheckboxSelections', checkboxSelections.join(','));

     // Append ModifiedCheckboxSelections as JSON string
     formData.append('ModifiedCheckboxSelections', JSON.stringify(modifiedCheckboxSelections));

     // Log FormData content
     for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
         console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
     }

     try {
         const response = await fetch("/UserInfoForm/edit", {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData,
         });

         if (response.ok) {
             console.log('Form submitted successfully');
         } else {
             console.error('Form submission failed');
         }
     } catch (error) {
         console.error('Error:', error);
     }
 };
```

The problem is when I click on submit that I put it in the jsx file the `CheckboxSelections` and `ModifiedCheckboxSelections` is getting the values that I give it to them but after I click on save in edit view the values for both changed to null what the wrong that I make it and how to fix it.

I tried everything and I change a lot of things in the jsx file and still the same thing

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you are seeing is most likely due to a bad assumption about passing entities between controllers and views. When first loading the view (I.e. View()) you are fetching an entity from the DbContext and likely eager loading related entities (checkbox selections) then passing that entity to be rendered in the view. For the submit you expect that this same entity and associations will be passed back. It isn't. What comes back to the controller is a collection of form data values that MVC will use to construct an entity. While you may have passed included entities to the view renderer, unless the view itself had elements to track each property of each instance of those related entities, the submit callback will not be able to populate them, so they will be null. This isn't a problem if your code doesn't rely on these in that submit action, but if you take that entity that was passed in, and send it back to the view engine via `View(tblUserInfo)`, that data is missing.

The simple fix: Ensure that you re-load the actual entity and related data to pass back to the view. For instance:

```
    var user = _context.Users
         .Include(x => x.CheckboxSelections)
         .AsNoTracking()
         .Single(x => x.UserId == userId);
    return View(user);
```

Note that it is recommended in this case to use `AsNoTracking` to ensure the current data state is returned since your code is performing various deletions and such.

I strongly recommend avoiding code like:

```
db.Entry(tblUserInfo).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

... on passed in "entities" from the view. These class instances are not the entities you sent to the view engine, they are merely composed from form data and can be incomplete and tampered with. Code like the above is trusting this quasi-entity as being a complete representation and can end up overwriting data you don't intend to be overwritten.

Instead you should always fetch the entity (and associations) in question, both to help validate that the data passed hasn't been tampered with, check that the  current real data state hasn't been modified since that copy was taken, (stale data overwrite) and ensure you are working with a complete set of data that you can then return to the view engine. For instance, fetch the user and their current "main forms" then go through the list of updated form selections, loading and associating any new selections to the user (adding to the loaded user.tblUserMainForms) and removing any existing references that are not in the  selections.

Normally given a list of selected FormIds,  this can be done using Linq:

```
var user = db.Users
    .Include(x => x.Forms)
    .Single(x => x.UserId == userId);

var existingFormIds = user.Forms.Select(x => x.FormId).ToList();
var formIdsToAdd = selectedFormIds.Except(existingFormIds);
var formIdsToRemove = existingFormIds.Except(selectedFormIds);

if(formIdsToRemove.Any())
{
    var formsToRemove = user.Forms
        .Where(x => formIdsToRemove.Contains(x.FormId))
        .ToList();
    foreach(var form in formsToRemove)
        user.Forms.Remove(form);
}
if(formIdsToAdd.Any())
{
    var formsToAdd = db.Forms
        .Where(x => formIdsToAdd.Contains(x.FormId))
        .ToList();
    foreach(var form in formsToAdd)
         user.Forms.Add(form);
}
db.SaveChanges();
return View(user);
```

The above is to just outline the pattern for updating associations. Depending on the specifics of how selections are passed (I.e. form names instead of Ids, etc.) and how your many-to-many relationship is mapped (I.e. using a joining entity or not) then the actual code would look somewhat different. The gist of the pattern though is to fetch the current data state for the user and their associations from the DB. Note, without using `AsNoTracking` as we will be relying on change tracking to save the changes. From there we identify what items need to be added and removed. For removed IDs we just get the associated items to remove and remove them from the user. For added IDs we fetch those entities and add them to the user. Change tracking does the rest when we call `SaveChanges` and since we loaded the user and their associated forms, we can send that user back to the view engine with the associations available. Note that we only needed the user ID and the updated selection IDs to perform this action rather than passing some manner of reconstructed entity. If the call takes in a quasi-entity the main thing is to not treat it / trust it to be a complete entity, it is merely a data container for data coming from the view.

Answer (score 0):

-> you're passing the CheckboxSelections and ModifiedCheckboxSelections values to the serverSide controller action method.

-> First check to your code in field name and IDs in the JSX file and view according to your form fields and model properties, and check your route to match your controller action method route.

-> Update Code :-

-> handleSubmit method in the selectMenu.jsx file setup to FormData object and append the value :-

```
handleSubmit = async (event) => {
event.preventDefault();

const { checkboxSelections, modifiedCheckboxSelections } = this.state;

const formData = new FormData();

// Append form fields
formData.append('UserID', document.getElementById("UserID").value);
formData.append('UserName', document.getElementById("UserName").value); 
   // Adjust with actual field IDs

   // Append CheckboxSelections as a comma-separated string
formData.append('CheckboxSelections', checkboxSelections.join(','));

   // Append ModifiedCheckboxSelections as JSON string
formData.append('ModifiedCheckboxSelections', 
JSON.stringify(modifiedCheckboxSelections));

try 
{
    const response = await fetch("/UserInfoForm/Edit", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        headers: {
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', // Add this header to 
                                                  // indicate AJAX request
            'RequestVerificationToken': 
   
   
       document.querySelector('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').
        value                   // Include anti-forgery token
        },
      });

      if (response.ok) {
          console.log('Form submitted successfully');
        } else {
           console.error('Form submission failed');
      }
    } catch (error) {
       console.error('Error:', error);
   }
};
```

-> View (Edit.cshtm file) in incudes the necessary field and anti-forgery token  :-

Code:-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "UserInfoForm", FormMethod.Post, new { 
enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<!-- Include other form fields here -->
<input type="hidden" id="UserID" name="UserID" value="@Model.UserID" />
<input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserName" value="@Model.UserName" 
/>

<!-- Other fields -->

<!-- Submit button -->
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

-> Than ServerSide controller action is correctly receive the formData and passing to CheckboxSelections and ModifiedCheckboxSelections :-

- Code:-

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = 
CheckboxSelections,ModifiedCheckboxSelections")] tblUserInfo tblUserInfo)
{
 Console.WriteLine($"Checkbox Selections: 
 {Request.Form["CheckboxSelections"]}");

  // Retrieve CheckboxSelections and ModifiedCheckboxSelections from the 
  //form data

 string checkboxSelections = Request.Form["CheckboxSelections"];
 string modifiedCheckboxSelections = 
 Request.Form["ModifiedCheckboxSelections"];

 // Handle CheckboxSelections and ModifiedCheckboxSelections as needed

 // Rest of your code
}
```